# tSQL pivot duplicating timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a SQL query that seems to be duplicating certain timestamps instead of correctly pivoting all the data into a single timestamp row.  Am i missing something crazy?

HELP?!

```
SELECT
     [time]
    ,DLPK
    ,IMBL
    ,THLD
    ,VEXC
    ,FLOW

FROM X

    PIVOT
    (
        max([value])
        FOR [tag2] IN (DLPK, IMBL, THLD, VEXC, FLOW)
    ) AS P

ORDER by [time]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide source data? If not you can put this query into subquery and do aggregation outside by [time] will solve the problem

Comment: interesting, soo... i had the source data built with CTEs (above and no luck).  i rolled the final source into a #TEMP and pulled the PIVOT from the #TEMP and it worked.  the CTE must retain some residual of the original data

Comment: Right, are there other columns in "x"?

Comment: the X does contain a row_number column... is that wtf is going on?

Comment: I think so, change your from clause to a sub query from x, leaving out that one

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation is simpler and less error-prone:

```
SELECT [time],
       MAX(CASE WHEN tag = 'DLPK' THEN value END) as dlpk,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tag = 'IMBL' THEN value END) as imbl,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tag = 'THLD' THEN value END) as thld,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tag = 'VEXC' THEN value END) as vexc,
       MAX(CASE WHEN tag = 'FLOW' THEN value END) as flow
FROM X
GROUP BY [time]
ORDER by [time]
```